# Is the word "models" appropriate here? Is "more" valid after "and"?

Tags: sentence-construction

> I will call him for advice what **models** of the appliances are cheaper, more convenient and **reliable**.

1. Is the word "models" appropriate here, or do I need to choose some other word?
2. Is "reliable" an absolute adjective here, or a comparative adjective? In other words, is "more" valid after "and"?

Comment: Yes, _models_ is appropriate, but if it's clear from the context which appliances you are talking about, it would be more natural just to say _what/which models are cheaper_.  You can say that one is _more reliable_ than others.

Comment: I would add ‘on’ after ‘advice’, although I don’t think it’s necessary.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, If there are four different types of appliances in that context, I guess that "what models of the appliances" is better appropriate here than simply "what models". Right? Is "more convenient and reliable" = "more convenient, more reliable"? Right? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Alon, Could you explain please why you think it's better to add "on"? What's the rule?